# State not storing input data if value is given

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I am trying to have an initial value in my input field before the user edits it. But when an initial value is given, it does erase when I try to remove it.

```
<Input
  type="text"
  placeholder={
  title === "" && fieldsFilled === false
  ? "This is a required field"
  : "Enter Title"
  }
  id="title"
  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
  style={
  title === "" && fieldsFilled === false
  ? styles
  : null
  }
/>
```

Why is my state not updating when I change. What is wrong with the `onChange`?

Answer (score 0):

Dont add initial value on `placeholder` use `value` to add it and initial value should come from hook as below

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('initial value')

<Input
  type="text"
  placeholder={
  title === "" && fieldsFilled === false
  ? "This is a required field"
  : "Enter Title"
  }
  id="title"
  value = {title}
  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
  style={
  title === "" && fieldsFilled === false
  ? styles
  : null
  }
/>
```

look on how i added the `value = {title}` on input tag, thats the key

Comment: Let me know if still having problem with it @Husnain Mehmood

Comment: I am getting data from another component

Comment: So I am storing that data in my state as initial value but it is not showing up in my input field